# Tkinter button doesn't work when I add an image on this button

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I'm creating a button with tkinter but I want to had an image on this button. When I make it, the button doesn't work. Nonetheless, when I remove the image of my button, it works..

```py
    # Creating a photoimage object to use image 
    photo = PhotoImage(file = r"C:/Users/toto/Documents/toto/img/Flechedroiteverte.png") 
    # Resizing image to fit on button 
    photoimage = photo.subsample(1, 1) 
    PageSuivante=Button(main_win, text = 'Click Me !', image = photoimage) 
    PageSuivante.grid(pady = 10)
```

Comment: "Doesn't work" does not describe the problem. What is not working?

Comment: Your code run perfectly fine for me, except that the text of the button is not visible because you haven't set the `compound` option to tell how the image should be situated wrt the text. BTW it would be better if you included the import statements and the creation of `main_win` in your code sample so that we can run it directly without having to figure out the missing pieces (See [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)). If there is an error, please include the traceback in your question as well.

Comment: Sorry, I add a code.. 
I do not handle the features of this forum very well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to keep a reference in a label, I have the same problem. You can do something like:

```
add = PhotoImage(file=r"C:/Users/toto/Documents/toto/img/Flechedroiteverte.png")
label = Label(image=add)
label.image = add # keep a reference!

PageSuivante=Button(main_win, text = 'Click Me !', image = add)
```

Comment: Yes It's ok! But Can I resize the image in the button?

Comment: I resize using Paint :D

Answer (score 0):

```
def ShowFramePrepaChantier(main_win,frame):

    delete_frame(main_win)
    frame.tkraise()
    frame.place(x=0, y=0)


    bouton_DownloadDPA = Button(frame, text='Valider mes DPA sélectionnées',padx = 200)
    bouton_DownloadDPA.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=SE)
    bouton_DownloadDPA.bind('<Button-1>', select)

    ## Creating a photoimage object to use image 
    photo = PhotoImage(file = r"C:/Users/toto/Documents/toto/img/Flechedroiteverte.png") 

    # Resizing image to fit on button 
    photoimage = photo.subsample(10, 10) 

    # here, image option is used to 
    # set image on button 
    # compound option is used to align 
    # image on LEFT side of button 
    bouton = Button(frame, text = 'Click Me !', image = photoimage, 
                        compound = LEFT)
    bouton.grid(pady = 100)







if __name__ == "__main__": 
    main_win = Tk()
    main_win.configure(bg='lavender')
    main_win.title("Test")
    main_win.geometry("680x400")


    second_frame = Frame(main_win)

    bouton_PrepaChantier = Button(main_win, text='Click to change frame', command=lambda:ShowFramePrepaChantier(main_win,second_frame), height=3, width=20)


    bouton_PrepaChantier.grid()

    main_win.mainloop()
```